# Using "to" along with "help"

Tags: prepositions

Do we use *to* along with *help*?

> This book helps to improve our knowledge

or

> This book helps improve our knowledge

Which one of these are correct?

Comment: Have you checked previous posts before asking?

Answer (score 1):

*Help* is one of the few lexical words which can be followed by either a bare infinitive or a *to*-infinitive. That means that both of those sentences are grammatical, but a native speaker would be more likely to use the second. The *to*-infinitive might be more likely when *help* has a direct object, as in *This book helps **us** to improve our knowledge.*

Comment: I think this has been asked umpteen times already and answered at least a few times on ELU.

Answer (score 0):

While Barrie was writing his answer, I found a very interesting and seemingly complete explanation in [this powerpoint](http://www.cc.ntut.edu.tw/~wwwmedia/course/Handout/100b/Grammar%20-%20Verbs%20%28handout%29.ppt) about *causative verbs*

> The verb help can be used with or without "to“, but 
>   many prefer it without to, especially in writing. Using 
>   “to” is more common in British English:
>
> Help Jim (to) clean up the mess.
>   Our teacher helped us (to) practice singing.
>   Judy helped me finish my assignment. (preferred by many for writing)
>   Judy helped me to finish my assignment. (sometimes heard in speaking)